# NLog: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-user-identity

Tags: oracle, nlog, appsettings

I try to implement NLog into my .NET Core Api web service.
I want to log to an Oracle database. All works well through an nlog.config XML file.

But the goal is to implement NLog config into appsettings.json and here problem occurs.
I get the error set in title:

> LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-user-identity

My config file is like this :

```
"NLog": {
    "autoReload": true,
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "internalLogLevel": "info",
    "internalLogFile": "c:/app/log/dev/internal-appsetting-nlog.txt",
    "extensions": {
        "NLog.Extensions.Logging": {
            "assembly": [
                "NLog.Extensions.Logging",
                "NLog.Web.AspNetCore"
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "var_logdir": "c:/app/log/dev"
    },
    "default-wrapper": {
        "type": "AsyncWrapper",
        "overflowAction": "Block"
    },
    "targets": {
        "all-file": {
            "type": "File",
            "fileName": "${var_logdir}/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log",
            "layout": {
                "type": "JsonLayout",
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "timestamp",
                        "layout": "${date:format=o}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "level",
                        "layout": "${level}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "logger",
                        "layout": "${logger}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "message",
                        "layout": "${message:raw=true}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "properties",
                        "encode": false,
                        "layout": {
                            "type": "JsonLayout",
                            "includeallproperties": "true"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "db": {
            "type": "Database",
            "commandText": "INSERT INTO logtable (LOGLEVEL,LOGGER,MESSAGE,MACHINENAME,USERNAME,CALLSITE, THREADID,EXCEPTIONMESSAGE,STACKTRACE,SESSIONID) VALUES (:pLEVEL,:pLOGGER,:pMESSAGE,:pMACHINENAME, :pCALLSITE,:pTHREADID,:pEXCEPTIONMESSAGE,:pSTACKTRACE)",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "@pLEVEL",
                    "layout": "${level}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pLOGGER",
                    "layout": "${logger}"
                },

                {
                    "name": "@pMESSAGE",
                    "layout": "${message}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pMACHINENAME",
                    "layout": "${machinename}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pUSERNAME",
                    "layout": "${aspnet-user-identity}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pCALLSITE",
                    "layout": "${callsite:filename=true}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pTHREADID",
                    "layout": "${threadid}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pEXCEPTIONMESSAGE",
                    "layout": "${exception}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pSTACKTRACE",
                    "layout": "${stacktrace}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "@pSESSIONID",
                    "layout": "${aspnet-sessionid}"
                }
            ],
            "dbProvider": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess",
            "connectionString": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "rules": [
        {
            "logger": "*",
            "minLevel": "Trace",
            "writeTo": "all-file"
        },
        {
            "logger": "*",
            "minLevel": "Trace",
            "writeTo": "db"
        },
        {
            "logger": "Microsoft.*",
            "maxLevel": "Info",
            "final": true
        }
    ]
},
```

The internal debugger reports:

```
2019-10-09 16:48:48.6665 Info Adding target AsyncTargetWrapper(Name=all-file)
2019-10-09 16:48:48.7859 Warn Error when setting property 'Layout' on 'NLog.Targets.DatabaseParameterInfo' Exception: System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-user-identity'. Is NLog.Web not included?
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String itemName)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.GetLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, String name)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.ParseLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, SimpleStringReader stringReader)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.CompileLayout(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, SimpleStringReader sr, Boolean isNested, String& text)
   at NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout.set_Text(String value)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, Object& newValue, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
```

Error occurs on `${aspnet-sessionid}`. If I comment out both layout, everything works well.

I found different things on GitHub issue report but all I tried was a fail.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unknown `aspnet-user-identity` is probably an issue with your extensions:

```
"extensions": [
  { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging" },
  { "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore" }
],
```

Could you try the above suggestion?

P.S. Updated the [wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Json-NLog-Config#extended-json-nlog-config-example) to include example of multiple "extensions"

Comment: Hi, nope, it doesn't work, it is exactly the same message in debug and in internal log too, I tried adding NLog.Web in the same way, but no luck.

Comment: @user2776069 Sorry about that. Had copied too much from your original example. Have now fixed the json, so it should work.

Comment: @user2776069 does it work now? Please accept then answer then :)